# create a link to run javascript in another window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link that when clicked on I want a new window opened, and in that window I want to run some javascipt code. This is how I create the link:

```
$('<a></a>').attr('href', 'javascript:my_func();').attr('target', '_blank')
```

my_func is run (I set a breakpoint in it and I confirmed that), and there are no errors. But the new window is not created. How can I do this?

EDIT: Trying to implement the solution suggested by @Barmar. Here is my code now:

```
lwv = load_wafer_viz_on_new_page.toString();
args = '"'+url+'","'+neighbor.data[0]+'","'+date+'"';
lwv += 'load_wafer_viz_on_new_page(' + JSON.stringify(args) + ');'
$('<a></a>').attr('href', 'javascript:var w = window.open();w.innerHTML = "<html><head></head></html>";var script = w.document.createElement("script");script.textContent = lwv;w.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);');
```

I'm getting a blank page. How do I incorporate this solution into my clickable link?

Comment: `_blank` windows have no content (code OR html). that's why they're "blank". If you want to run code there, then you'll have to add the code to that new window first.

Comment: This sounds like an attempted solution to a problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I currently have a link that calls a js function and causes new content to be created on the same page you're on. But now I want to create that content in a new window.

Comment: @acupajoe This isn't quite the same, in this question he doesn't want to open a URL in the new window.

Comment: Try creating `html` as string , including jQuery , `script` elements that create , retrieve content in `html` string , calling `window.open()` with string as content of `data URI` . Though requested resources should have `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin` headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the window and then inject a `<script>` tag into its DOM.

```
var w = window.open();
w.innerHTML = '<html><head></head></html>';
var script = w.document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = "alert('running');";
w.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/pgn7b6L8/2/)

If you want to get a function definition into the window and then call that function, you can do:

```
script.textContent = functionName.toString();
script.textContent += 'functioName(' + JSON.stringify(arg) + ');'
```

Here's a working version of your code:

```
neighbor = {
    data: [1, 2, 3]
}
date = "today";
function load_wafer_viz_on_new_page(a, b) {
    alert(a + b);
}
window.lwv = load_wafer_viz_on_new_page.toString();
args = JSON.stringify(neighbor.data[0]) + ',' + JSON.stringify(date);
lwv += 'load_wafer_viz_on_new_page(' + args + ');'
$("a").attr('href', 'javascript:var w = window.open();w.innerHTML = "<html><head></head></html>";var script = w.document.createElement("script");script.textContent = lwv;w.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/9dndqp7h/3/)

Comment: How would I make `script.textContent` be the contents of a js fucntion that I have access to in the current page?

Comment: You can use `function.toString()` to get the definition of the function as a string.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about that function. What about the arguments to the function. How do I get those into the stringafied function?

Comment: I've added an example of how to add a call to the function.

Comment: I updated my original post to show how my code is now. I'm not sure how to integrate your solution into my clickable link.

Comment: Don't try to do it all in inline Javascript. Put the code into a function, and do `href="javascript:funcName()"`

Comment: Well, yes I am going to do that once I have it working. I changed it (and updated the OP) to remove the `attr('target', '_blank')` but I still am getting a blank page and no errors.

Comment: Open the developer tools in the new window to see what the script looks like.

Comment: The new window is empty. No script, no HTML, no nothing. I'm going to have to do some debugging and see if I can see what is going on.

Comment: You shouldn't stringify multiple args as one string. You need to stringify each argument separately, and pass them each as a separate argument to the function.

Comment: Also, don't put quotes around the arguments after you stringify them, that's one of the things that stringify does.

Comment: Getting closer. I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. My js function uses jQuery and Angular and they are not loaded on the new page when the function runs. Not sure how to load them to the new page.

Comment: You need to add `<script>` elements to the new page that load them. Basically, your function has to completely build the new page, with everything it needs. One window can't call functions from another window. Why are you doing it this way instead of just loading a page from the server that does everything?

Comment: It's complicated - I currently have a link that calls a js function and causes new content to be created on the same page you're on. But now I want to create that content in a new window. That js function creates a div and then calls the load method of the div passing a URL in. That causes HTML to be returned then the function calls other functions, some in Angular.

Comment: LIke I said, if you want to create it in a new window, you have to fill in the entire contents, you can't use anything from the current page directly.

Comment: Got it. I appreciate all the help. I probably will not have time to work on this again until next week.

Comment: I decided to do this the right way and load a page from the server. I thought it would be more work, but as is so often the case, doing it the right way was less work. But I leaned a lot from this and I really appreciate the help.